# Discord.js bot picking skin color for emojis

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am working on a certain embed my bot will send, where emojis will be used. As a user I can choose the skin color of certain emojis. But I can't think of a way to tell the bot not to use this ugly yellowish.

Thanks in advance!

`{name: "Title": value: ":muscle:"}`
*Thats how I use it*

Comment: Isn't the pigment option a setting per-user? If the originator picked the default, there in no way to change the message.

Comment: can I make the bot choose a pigment?

Comment: I don't believe you can detect the user's setting, but you can send one with a modifier e.g. `:muscle_tone1:`. Just add `_tone<x>` where `x` is `1-5`, before the closing colon. The pigment is to reflect the person speaking. If it is a bot, then it's ok to send the default yellow.

Comment: make pls an answer and I will approve it to close my thread 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can detect the user's setting, but you can send one with a modifier e.g. `:muscle_tone1:`. This will result in the following to be rendered:

> `:muscle::skin-tone-1:`

This modifier determines the [Emoji Modifier Sequence](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-modifier-sequence/) for the output.

Just add `_tone<x>` where `x` is `1-5`, before the closing colon. The pigment is to reflect the person speaking. If it is a bot, then it's ok to send the default yellow.

---

In the Discord release notes, they state the following:

> **People Emoji** can now change skin color as part of the new Unicode 8 support. Pop open the Emoji Picker and choose your preferred color ***to be yourself***, and ***not someone else***. `:ok_hand::skin-tone-2:`

Source: [Discord: 2016.4.8 — Change Log](https://blog.discord.com/2016-4-8-change-log-7d8d6f386613)